# How do I use a function with loops that can change data values?

Tags: function, loops

I am trying to convert specific columns of my study where I am flipping 1-5 to 5-1 so 1 would be a 5, 2  would be a 4, etc. The function works when I ask it to return something but when I use this code, my data values stay the same. What can I do such that I can convert data because I know my function is able to read it.

```
flip = function(x){
  for(i in 1:198){
    if(x[i] == 1){
      return(5)
      x[i] = 5
      next
    }
    if(x[i] == 2){
      return(4)
      x[i] = 4
      next
    }
    if(x[i] == 4){
      return(2)
      [i] = 2
      next
    }
    if(x[i] == 5){
      return(1)
      x[i] = 1
      next
    }
  }
}

flip(data$y1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: is your 15th line really supposed to be `[i] =2`  or is it a typo and you wanted 'x[i]=2'?

Comment: A friendly advice: you can use packages to create your function with more concise code, as in: `flip<-function(x){dplyr::case_when(x==1 ~ 5, x==2 ~ 4, x==3 ~ 3, x==4 ~ 2, x==5 ~ 1)
}` - you would still have to adapt it to your 1:198 sequence which I dont understand